# Android Studio Built-in Changelog

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to `Android Studio` and unfamiliar with `JavaDoc`.  Does android studio have a way to a quick easily accessable way to keep a simple status or note about the most recent changes to the app? or am I better off creating a text file and keeping it in there or just leaving it in comments?

I'm using `Git` so I could just check commit messages but I was looking for something quicker.

I was just wondering if there was a built in mechanism.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `View|Tool Windows|Changes` if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It does not exist in Android Studio 4.0